# Java library/api which converts language code to language name

Tags: java, nlp, converters, iso

Is there a Java library/api which , given an iso language code, returns the corresponding language name. For example zh-cn should return chinese, en should return english and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java Locale class can do this:

```
new Locale("zh", "cn").getDisplayName();
--> Chinese (China)
```

You just have to parse the language/country names.

Comment: Note you can also call display name with parameters to get the localized lang description getDisplayName(Locale objectLocale, Locale displayLocale) otherwise it will use the enviorment locale!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a library; you can use `java.util.Locale` for this.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "cn");
System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage());
```

This will print

```
Chinese
```

Answer (score 1):

[Locale API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) does the country code for java languages.Refer the above link